# Running command lines in python

Tags: python

I'm having troubles running commands lines in python.
I'm currently using

```
os.system("cd " + path)
os.system(command)
```

However, os.system opens a new console each time.

What class should i use for it to work ?
How can I intercept the output ?

Thanks !

Comment: Which OS? Which version of Python?

Comment: There _was_ no 1.7. I remember the 1.6->2.0 conversion like it was just yesterday and the entire dotcom economy was collapsing and I had lots of time to sit around at home reading PEPs. Maybe you mean 2.7?

Comment: Sorry I can't edit... Typo it's the 2.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

The advantage of `subprocess` versus `system` is that it is more flexible. You can get the stdout, stderr, the "real" status code, better error handling, etc.

Also, check out [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module).

Comment: call(["cd", "C:\Users\Greed"], shell=True)                         with                                                                call(["C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\v3.5\csc.exe", "/optimize", "/out:Main.exe",  "C:\Users\Greed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Ref\Ref\Program.cs"]) seems to not work ?

Comment: @Greed: Each `call` with `shell=True` is running in its own shell. Doing a `cd` there is just going to change that shell's current directory; it won't affect the next one. If you want to actually change the current directory for the Python script, and everything else it launches, use `os.chdir` instead. Then the `call` should work. (If not, explain what it does wrong instead of just saying it "seems to not work".)

Comment: @Ophion ...Which begs the question, *is there a reason the OP is running such an old version of Python?*

Comment: @IanAtkin: It's not even an old version, it's a version that never existed, or was even contemplated. So clearly, the OP is from a different universe. Possibly one where Guido has no beard!

Comment: Wow, you're right. I Google'd it and didn't notice I was looking at *Python Paste 1.7.5*. BTW: Guido's beard is a fake that he only uses at Py Conventions.

Comment: @IanAtkin: Hmmm… I just read that on the internet, so it must be true. Which means in the OP's universe, Guido has a real beard that he only covers up at Py Conventions?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the above:

```
os.chdir(path)
os.system(command)
```

To capture data I would look into subprocess: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Since you are using python 1.7:

```
output=os.popen(command,"r").readlines()
```

Comment: There is no python 1.7. And before 2.0, `os.popen` was broken on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I always use   `os.chdir("dirname")`   This function can work just like the cd function, so you can do both   `os.chdir("dir_thats_right_here")`  and   `os.chdir("/dir/thats/far/away")`